# Why does the nav2d_karto mapper.yaml have particles?

Tags: ros, nav2d, wiki, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I cannot figure out theoretically why does the Karto Mapper provided in the [nav2d](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d) package uses also particles for mapping. From the basic SLAM theory I've studied, a graph-based SLAM algorithm does not need particles to maintain and compute the pose of the robot, so what are those particles intended for? Can someone quickly sketch me the main steps of this Karto algorithms used in this package?

Sorry for the quite simple question,

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294861/why-does-the-nav2d_karto-mapper.yaml-have-particles?/) by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It uses a MCL filter for localization, the particles are for that. Karto itself does not use particles, you're right on the money there. It's scan matching based.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-06-21**:
Hi @smac, thanks for replying! So just for me to fully understand, the front end and back end of the Karto are only use for mapping right?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-06-21**:
karto is for SLAM: localization and mapping. After you have a map built that you're localizing in, that's what the pf is for.

If this answers the question, please hit the check mark so it closes the issue